# multiply matrices

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix

I wrote a program that calculates the multiplication of two matrices (of compatible dimensions) where each element of the resulting matrix is ​​calculated by a separate thread. Each thread calculates a single element in the resulting matrix

My question is, what else could I improve or what problems does implementation have? Possible bugs?

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 4

void *mult(void* arg)
{
    int *data = (int *)arg;
    int k = 0, i = 0;

    int x = data[0];
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
        k += data[i]*data[i+x];

    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *p = k;

    pthread_exit(p);
}


int main()
{

    int matA[MAX][MAX];
    int matB[MAX][MAX];


    int r1=MAX,c1=MAX,r2=MAX,c2=MAX,i,j,k;


    // Generates arbitrary values ​​in matrix A
    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < c1; j++)
                matA[i][j] = rand() % 10;

        // Generates arbitrary values ​​in matrix B
    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < c1; j++)
                matB[i][j] = rand() % 10;

    // Displays matrix A    
    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c1; j++)
            printf("%d ",matA[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Displays matrix B            
    for (i = 0; i < r2; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < c2; j++)
            printf("%d ",matB[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }


    int max = r1*c2;


    //declaring the resulting matrix by multiplying the rows by the columns 
    pthread_t *threads;
    threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(max*sizeof(pthread_t));

    int count = 0;
    int* data = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < r1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < c2; j++)
            {

            //storage of elements resulting from multiplication
            data = (int *)malloc((20)*sizeof(int));
            data[0] = c1;

            for (k = 0; k < c1; k++)
                data[k+1] = matA[i][k];

            for (k = 0; k < r2; k++)
                data[k+c1+1] = matB[k][j];


                pthread_create(&threads[count++], NULL,
                            mult, (void*)(data));

                    }

    printf("The result of multiplication is : \n");
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
    void *k;


    pthread_join(threads[i], &k);


        int *p = (int *)k;
    printf("%d ",*p);
    if ((i + 1) % c2 == 0)
        printf("\n");
    }



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this just an exercise in multithreading or is the intention to accelerate the matrix multiplication? My guess would be that allocating and copying the rows and columns takes more time than a direct multiplication.

Comment: it's just a multiplication of arrays using threads

Answer (score 1):

My eyes immediately fell on these lines:

> ```
> int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
>     *p = k;
> ```

The odd indentation is easily fixed, of course.

The unnecessary cast is just as easily removed.

The more serious bug is assigning to `*p` when `p` could be **a null pointer**.

Possible replacement code:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
if (!p) {
    return arg;
}
```

(`arg` is about the only pointer we can return that's valid after the thread terminates - I'm not sure if we can safely return `NULL` instead.  If that's safe, it would be a clearer indication of failure, I think.)

The other allocations all have the same problem.  Also, I see no corresponding calls to `free()`, so we have memory leaks all over the place.  You'll get away with this in a small short-lived program, but that will prevent you being able to reuse your implementation more generally.

Comment: thanks for the review. How about overflow? It exists in my program?

Comment: The error code shouldn't be used to return allocated memory addresses I suppose, right?

Comment: Value overflow?  Yes, you have nothing to prevent that.  And signed overflow is undefined behaviour, so really worth avoiding.  I'll let some other review mention that properly - I just picked up this one problem.